# How can I get permanent URL of file uploaded on rackspace using python pyrax

Tags: python, rackspace, pyrax

I am able to to upload image successfully.
My code is:

```
pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_credentials("myuser_name", "my_api_key", region="ORD")
cf = pyrax.cloudfiles
cont = cf.create_container("media")
cont.make_public()
print "Beginning upload..."
obj = cont.upload_file(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + "/" + str(filename))
print obj.get_temp_url
print cont
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acquire a publicly-accessible URI of an object by joining its name with the `cdn_uri` or `cdn_ssn_url` of its container:

```python
# Public URI
cont.cdn_uri + '/' + obj.name

# Public SSL URI
cont.cdn_ssl_uri + '/' + obj.name
```